# Asp.Net Core Route is not working properly

Tags: routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I searched a lot of questions and no one seems to address my specific problem.

I was reading some tutorials and the `[Route("Text")]` is not working as in the tutorials.

So with this code:

```
 public class AboutController
    {
        public string Copyright() {
            return "\u00a9 Copyright are the best";
        }

        public string Year() {
            return "2016";
        }
    }
```

I can go to `localhost:xxx/about/copyright` and `localhost:xxx/about/year` with no problems. 
However if I try adding [Route("what")] immediately before the declaration of `AboutController` I now can't navigate to `localhost:xxx/what/copyright` or `localhost:xxx/what/year`.
However if I try this:

```
 [Route("what/[action]")]
    public class AboutController
    {
        [Route("rights")]
        public string Copyright() {
            return "\u00a9 Copyright are the best";
        }

        public string Year() {
            return "2016";
        }
    }
```

I can go to `localhost:xxx/what/year` but not to `localhost:xxx/what/rights`(or `localhost:xxx/what/copyright` for that matter.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you add `[Route("rights")]` to `Copyright()`, that is interpreted as `localhost:xxx/what/copyright/rights`.

so using your last example:

```
 [Route("what/[action]")]//url is: localhost:xxx/what/someactionname
public class AboutController
{
    [Route("rights")]//url is: localhost:xxx/what/copyright/rights --since CopyRight() is the action
    public string Copyright() {
        return "\u00a9 Copyright are the best";
    }

    public string Year() { //localhost:xxx/what/year --since Year() is the action
        return "2016";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So, how do I change the route of the Controller to `what` instead of `home` (`localhost:xxx/what/..` instead of `localhost:xxx/home/...`) ? In the tutorial I was watching they simply did [Route("what")] before the `public class `AboutController`.

Comment: remove the `/[action]` portion on the controller, then on `Year()` add `[Route("year")]`.  That would give you `localhost:xxx/what/year` and `localhost:xxx/what/rights`

Comment: Yes, that is the solution. But again, I want to add that in the tutorial it was not not like this (maybe a different MVC version?)

Comment: @JoãoPereira: Alternatively write the full route as absolute path: `[Route("/what/rights"]`

Comment: Yes, that also works @Tseng.
But the question here, from what I understand is if you put a Route on one method, you need to do that for all of them Am I correct?

Comment: @JoãoPereira: No, the route on the class always acts as prefix and is added to all actions w/o a route or HttpXXX Attribute. You can override the route with additional `[Route("newActionRouteName")]` or add to the default by adding two attributes: `[Route("[action]")][Route("rights")]` and when the route starts with `/` its an absolute route and the prefix route from class gets ignored

Comment: So, if I only insert `[Route("rights")]` before `Copyright()` method  without any other insertion, are you saying that the link `localhost:xxx/about/rights` will work? Because I tested and it doesn't

Comment: @JoãoPereira it may depend on what you have set for the default MVC template in Startup.cs (the app.UseMvc method)

Comment: I'm using `app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);` where `private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");`